# Getting error when generating sign apk ,No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/global_tracker')

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am getting error

> "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with
>   value '@xml/global_tracker')"

while generating signed apk..

It gives me error at `/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml`

In res/xml folder file seems like :
globle_tracker.xml(debug)

Answer (score 1):

it will be created file for debug mode only.we have recreated the same file with different name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Step 2 [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start).

This is probably an error generated while you were integrating Google Analytics I suppose.

Comment: I have checked and everything is as per document.
It works fine while generating debug apk, but shows error on creating signed apk. :(

Comment: Did you add your SHA key of the keystore too? That might be one of the reasons why it is not generating the signed apk

Comment: thank you. we have recreated the same file with different name and it worked.